# ExtJs - How to load TreeStore with dynamic parameters

Tags: json, extjs, tree, load, store

My tree with treestore gets initially loaded but requesting children nodes fails.

When requesting children, a parameter `localpath` is transmitted that defines the path where children data is located.

Init request: `localpath=/` -> gets all children in `/`

Children request: `localpath=/subfolder1` -> gets all children in `/subfolder1`

I have attached two screenshots showing initial load and showing when folders clicked.

[image: Folders initially loaded]

[image: Folders clicked but no children]

BTW: Where are the arrows gone in my tree?

**Json**: My tree stores receives json data like this:

```
{
    "value": {
      "name": "",
      "path": "/",
      "leaf": false,
      "type": "folder",
      "children": [
        {
          "name": "subfolder1",
          "path": "/subfolder1",
          "leaf": false,
          "type": "folder",
          "children": []
        },
        {
          "name": "subfolder2",
          "path": "/subfolder2",
          "leaf": false,
          "type": "folder",
          "children": []
        },
        {
          "name": "testreports",
          "path": "/testreports",
          "leaf": false,
          "type": "folder",
          "children": []
        }
      ]
    }
}
```

**Store**: the tree store looks like this:

```
 var oTreeStore = Ext.create( 'X.module.store.store.Tree', {
    model    : 'X.module.store.model.TreeNode',
    api      : this.httpApi,
    module   : "store",
    func     : "getchildren",
    scope    : "user"
 } );
```

**TreePanel** creation:

```
 var oTreePanel = Ext.create( 'X.module.store.view.TreePanel', {
    store       : oTreeStore
 } );
```

**TreePanel** definition:

```
    constructor: function( oConfig ) {

     var self = this;
     //creating a proxy, which can communicate with HTTP-API
     //and is able to parse it's json-tree format

     var oProxy = Ext.create( 'X.lib.httpapiclient.Proxy', {
        api     : oConfig.api,
        module  : oConfig.module,
        func    : oConfig.func,
        params  : {
           scope       : oConfig.scope
        },
        reader  : {
           type: 'json',
           root: function( o ) { return o.value? o.value.children : o.children; }
        },
        delay   : oConfig.delay || 100,
        success : oConfig.success || function() {},
        progress: oConfig.progress || function() {},
        error   : oConfig.error || function() {}
     } );

     oConfig.nodeParam = 'localpath';
     oConfig.proxy = oProxy;

     self.callParent( arguments );

     //the HTTP-API requires the ID of the root-node to be empty
     self.on( 'beforeload', function( s, o ) {
        if( o.params.localpath === 'root' ) o.params.localpath = '/';
     } );


  }
```

**Model**: the model...

```
   Ext.define( 'X.module.store.model.TreeNode', {
      extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
      fields: [
         { name: 'name',         type: 'string' },
         { name: 'path',         type: 'string' },
         { name: 'type',         type: 'string' }
      ]
   } );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to provide children in the `children` property. In my case I was delivering empty children like this `children: []`. So there was nothing to show.